# PHP - Testing array for multiple conditions

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that is filtered resulting in an array:

```
$arr_sublineitems[$lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['SubLineItemId']]=[
                            'VendorId' => $lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['VendorId'],
                            'Quantity' => $lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['Quantity'],
                            'SellPrice' => $lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['SellPrice'],
                            'FreightSell' => $lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['FreightSell'],
                            'NetPrice' => $lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['NetPrice'],
                            'FreightNet' => $lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['FreightNet'],
                            'Taxable' => $lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['Taxable'],
                            'ProjectId' => $project_id,
                            'Total_Sell' => ($lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['SellPrice'] * $lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['Quantity'])
```

Within the resulting array, I need to aggregate Total_Sell based on taxable/non-taxable and >0 or <0 (i.e. a charge or a credit) by vendor prior to moving to database.  Each vendor could meet all four possible conditions if they have multiple items in $arr_sublineitems so I'm thinking to parse $arr_sublineitems into 4 arrays using the VendorId as key for the new arrays: $arr_sublineitem_taxable, $arr_sublineitems_nontaxable, $arr_sublineitems_taxable_credit and $arr_sublineitems_nontaxable_credit.  Each vendor could have a row in one or more of the parsed arrays, but only one row per array.

If tried this with foreach and multiple if/else but I need to exit when a condition is met and the values from $arr_sublineitems is added to one of the parsed arrays...  I cannot figure out how to make this happen using break/continue or a switch statement...  My current code is:

```
foreach($arr_sublineitems as $key => $item){
    if($item['Total_Sell'] > 0 && $item['Taxable']){
        if(!isset($arr_sublineitems[$item]['VendorId'])){
            $arr_sublineitems_taxable[$item]['VendorId'] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                'Total_Sell' => $item['VendorId']['Total_Sell']
            );
        }else{
            $arr_sublineitems_taxable[$item]['VendorId']['Total_Sell']+= $item['Total_Sell'];
        }

    }
    if($item['Total_Sell'] > 0 && !($item['Taxable'])){
        if(!isset($arr_sublineitems[$key]['VendorId'])){
            $arr_sublineitems_nontaxable[$key]['VendorId'] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                'Total_Sell' => $item['Total_Sell']);
        }else{
            $arr_sublineitems_nontaxable[$key]['VendorId']['Total_Sell']+= $item['Total_Sell'];
        }
    }

    if($item['Total_Sell'] < 0 && $item['Taxable']){
        if(!isset($arr_sublineitems[$key])){
            $arr_sublineitems_taxable_credit[$key] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                'Total_Sell_Credit' => $item['Total_Sell']);
        }else{
            $arr_sublineitems_nottaxable_credit[$key]['Total_Sell_Credit']+= $item['Total_Sell_Credit'];
        }
    }
    if($item['Total_Sell'] < 0 && !($item['Taxable'])){
        if(!isset($arr_sublineitems[$key])){
            $arr_sublineitems_taxable_credit[$key] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                'Total_Sell_Credit' => $item['Total_Sell']);
        }else{
            $arr_sublineitems_nottaxable_credit[$key]['Total_Sell_Credit']+= $item['Total_Sell_Credit'];
        }
    }
}
```

I have edited my code to this:

```
foreach($arr_sublineitems as $key => $item) {

                    $vendor_id = $item['VendorId'];

                    if (!array_key_exists($vendor_id, $arr_vendor_totals)) {

                        if ($item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] > 0) {
                            $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                                'Total_Taxable' => $item['Total_Sell']);

                            } elseif ($item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] < 0) {
                                $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_Credit_Taxable'] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                                    'Total_Taxable' => $item['Total_Sell']);

                            } elseif (!$item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] > 0) {
                                $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_NonTaxable'] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                                    'Total_Taxable' => $item['Total_Sell']);

                            } elseif (!$item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] < 0) {
                                $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_Credit_NonTaxable'] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                                    'Total_Taxable' => $item['Total_Sell']);
                            }
                            continue;
                        }

                    if (array_key_exists($vendor_id, $arr_vendor_totals)){

                        if ($item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] > 0) {
                            $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_Taxable'] += $item['Total_Sell'];

                        } elseif ($item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] < 0) {
                            $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_Credit_Taxable'] += $item['Total_Credit_Taxable'];

                        } elseif (!$item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] > 0) {
                            $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_NonTaxable'] += $item['Total_NonTaxable'];

                        } elseif (!$item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] < 0) {
                            $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_Credit_NonTaxable'] += $item['Total_Credit_NonTaxable'];
                        }
                    }
                }
```

@Chris Haas - the data is provided in json associative multidimensional array.

```
PurchaseOrders": [
    {
    "PurchaseOrderId": "9809ae4b-3123-4799-8549-9edc09105188",
    "VendorId": "b0ddcf4d-894e-4ffc-ab99-e71676d1a566",
    "PONumber": "9999791",
    "ReceivedDate": null,
    "POSentDate": null
    },
...

"SubLineItems": [
    {
        "SubLineItemId": "0f349da9-8b25-4ec5-9b5a-e9d0d90d11cd",
        "ItemTypeCode": 0,
        "ItemTypeDescription": "Normal",
        "VendorId": "b0ddcf4d-894e-4ffc-ab99-e71676d1a566",
        "PurchaseOrderId": "9809ae4b-3123-4799-8549-9edc09105188",
        "FreightDataId": null,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "SellPrice": 353.440150801131,
        "SellTotal": 503.44,
        "FreightSell": 150.0,
        "InstallationSell": 0.0,
        "NetPrice": 750.0,
        "FreightNet": 100.0
    },
...
```

Vendors can have 1..n Purchase Orders, Purchase Orders can have 1..n Line Items, Line Items can have 1..n SubLineItems...

I am trying to aggregate/sum SubLineItems two ways - 1) by vendor: taxable, non-taxable >0 SellPrice and taxable/non-taxable <0 SellPrice and 2) by PurchaseOrderID taxable, non-taxable >0 SellPrice and taxable/non-taxable <0 SellPrice.

Thank you for looking at this... I'm going to look at @Riggs Folly's solution also.

Comment: Where is this data sourced? If it is coming from some kind of database, you might be better off using the database engine to do your grouping.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff that feels like a potential bug in that code. For instance, in your inner `if statement you are checking `$arr_sublineitems`, but sometimes by a `$item` as a sub-array, sometimes by `$key` as a sub-array, and sometimes just by `$key`. That might be totally valid, but it also feels magical/arbitrary. Your third and fourth full blocks also appear to have the wrong array being assigned to. Comments _might_ help, but it also might help to abstract this magic array to something that is easier to conceive, such as an object.

Comment: @TheGentleman - it's coming from a json file, headed to a db.

Comment: @Chris Haas - I totally agree, looking for clarity on the best way to approach, I'm working on simplification...

Comment: Unfortunately the source array that you've provided is really hard to understand, so it is hard to go much further. Specifically, `$arr_sublineitems[$lineitem_data[$j]['SubLineItems'][$k]['SubLineItemId']]`. Maybe if you could product a redacted subset of the JSON itself, unless it is already in array format? We often create very light-weight throwaway classes for this, called DTO's, that just help us reason at a higher level. Maybe start with creating a simple `Item` class, that has the fields you need

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using the latest code I posted. It provides the desired result and is easy for me to understand.  I'm sure they are better ways and would lot to know if someone sees a more efficient way to handle this.

The code I am using is:

```
foreach($arr_sublineitems as $key => $item) {

   $vendor_id = $item['VendorId'];

      if (!array_key_exists($vendor_id, $arr_vendor_totals)) {

         if ($item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] > 0) {
            $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'], 'Total_Taxable' => $item['Total_Sell']);

         } elseif ($item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] < 0) {
              $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_Credit_Taxable'] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                                    'Total_Taxable' => $item['Total_Sell']);

         } elseif (!$item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] > 0) {
             $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_NonTaxable'] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                                    'Total_Taxable' => $item['Total_Sell']);

        } elseif (!$item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] < 0) {
            $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_Credit_NonTaxable'] = array('FreightSell' => $item['FreightSell'],
                                    'Total_Taxable' => $item['Total_Sell']
       }
        continue;
    }
```

if (array_key_exists($vendor_id, $arr_vendor_totals)){

```
  if ($item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] > 0) ={$arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_Taxable'] += $item['Total_Sell'];

    } elseif ($item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] < 0) {
       $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_Credit_Taxable'] += $item['Total_Credit_Taxable'];

     } elseif (!$item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] > 0) {
        $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_NonTaxable'] += $item['Total_NonTaxable'];

     } elseif (!$item['Taxable'] && $item['Total_Sell'] < 0) {
       $arr_vendor_totals[$vendor_id]['Total_Credit_NonTaxable'] += $item['Total_Credit_NonTaxable'];
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).